# How to tell another thread that one thread is within recv() call *now*

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, system-calls, recv

There is an embedded Linux system with an externally connected (ethernet) device which sends lots of UDP data, once it's started by a command.
At startup, I have one thread which is to continuously receive UDP data for the remainder of the program runtime.
As I see it, for reliability in principle, not just by accident, it must be ensured that the UDP reception loop must make its first call to recv() before the external data source is started, or the first packet or so might me lost, depending on scheduler whims. (this is all in a very local, purposefully simple network setup - packet loss is normally not an issue and not handled - speed is king)
Currently, right before calling that UDP reception code, I start a temporary thread which delays for some time, then enables the data source to send UDP data.
This is currently the way to "ensure" that the first UDP packet arrives when the reception thread is "armed", i.e. within a recv() call, the OS waiting for data.

Even if I, say, set a condition variable, right before the first call to recv() to tell the rest of the program "ok, you can enable the data source now, I'm ready" - it could, in theory, happen that there is some scheduling induced delay between that signal flagging and the actual call to recv (or/and for the internals of recv actually being ready).

Is there a more elegant / proper way to solve this, than using some "empirical delay time"?

Pseudo code for illustration:

```
// ******** main thread ********
thread delayed( [&]{ sleepMs(500); enableUdpDataSource(); } );
thread udpRecv( [&]{ udpRecvUntilTimeout() } );
delayed.join();
udpRecv.join();
return 0;

// ******** UDP thread ********
void udpRecvUntilTimeout()
{
  udpInit(); // set up socket, buffer sizes etc

  while (shouldRun)
  {
    // recv() needs to be "armed" *before* the data source is enabled.
    // If I set a condition variable for another thread right here,
    // there may be a scheduling intervention between it and the actual
    // engaging of recv() - when the other thread happily enables the datasource.
    int received = recv( sockFd, buf, maxlen, 0 );
    timeoutWatchdogReset();
    processReceivedData();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no reliability in UDP. You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.

Comment: I'm aware that that's the case in general. But in a system with one integrated switch and 2..3 participants? Other than the kernel being overly busy for some reason - why/were could packets be dropped?

Comment: There is nothing you can do to _guarantee_ that the temp thread won't enable the data source before the receiver thread actually is awaiting the first packet. But if the `sleep()` call works for you, then you might be able to reduce the duration of the sleep by having the receiver thread increment a Semaphore just before it calls `recv()`, and by having the temp thread; await the semaphore, _then_ sleep, then enable the transmitter.

Comment: You want reliability in principal, yet cannot handle packet loss, and believe speed is king.  There are contradictions here.  If you want your program to be reliable, then handle packet loss not as a failure, but as an expected input to your program.  Then you can handle any startup ordering.   Almost anything is more elegant than “some empirical delay time” which is also known as a “race condition”.

Comment: "believe speed is king" maybe bad wording: it's a requirement. Also, timing jitter seems pretty low with UDP and certain scheduling settings for the thread.
As for contradiction - this is not all one big blob, there are several issues and I'd like to make as many of them as small as possible. But I hear ya. For now it looks like some compromises can't be gotten around. I was told, previously developed systems use UDP in similar vein, still made & sold, & that kind of data connection is expected where it's used. That much I have to take as it is.

Comment: Solomon Slow - true, that could make it slightly less nasty.
Also I just realised I haven't about the fact that the UDP receive thread uses a mean "RT-ish" scheduling setting with priority (on a non-RT kernel), whereas that datasource enabler thread does not. That would seem to shift things a bit wrt "guarantees" of which comes first - I'm just not deep enough into that API to know the exact ramifications.
I'll try to update my question to reflect that when I have more time, although there is the danger of making the question "too broad" or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an earlier version, I suggested that the call to `bind` is optional, but of course it is not. You have to call it in order to tell the kernel which UDP port to open.
After `bind`, the kernel will buffer incoming UDP packets and you can call `recv` if you're not interested in the client network details (otherwise, call `recvfrom`).

Something along these lines:

```
char buf[1500];
struct sockaddr_in addr;

int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) 1234); // UDP port

bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

// start data sending thread

sleep(1); // for testing

recv(sd, buf, 100, 0);
```

But there are no guarantees with UDP; you might still lose packets (eg. if the sender is overloading the receiver)

Comment: You have to `bind()` AND `connect()` in order to use `recv()` for UDP.  Otherwise, if you just `bind()` only, you have to use `recvfrom()` instead. But either way, you have to `bind()` first no matter what before you can receive anything, since `bind()` establishes the local port to receive on. You can use `setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)` to increase the buffer size, if needed, to avoid packets being discarded before you can read them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `bind` is indeed necessary to open the UDP server port (that was not clear and I edited that), but you can still call `recv` (or `read`) if you are not interested in client network details. The `connect` is optional and only for the client; It simply registers the socket and network address with the kernel so that you can call `send` (or `write`) instead of `sendto`.

Comment: The advantage for a UDP client calling `connect` is that if the port is not available, the 'ICMP unreachable' is delivered to the process upon a follow-up system call on the socket (by returning an error). Without `connect`, the kernel cannot deliver the error because it has no way of knowing that the socket and network address are related.

Comment: @LWimsey: UDP doesn't have clients and servers.  At the datagram level, there's just a sender and receiver, and data in both directions is treated perfectly symmetrically.  You are correct though that `recv()` can be used on a datagram socket without connection emulation.

Comment: @BenVoigt Terminology aside, I don't agree with 'exchange is symmetrical'. I suppose you refer to the absence of a handshake - true, but a server/receiver still has to indicate it's willing to accept UDP packets by opening a port (shown by `netstat`). That requires different system calls on either side, and I don't call that symmetrical.

Comment: "After bind, the kernel will buffer incoming UDP packets" -> Ah! That makes sense. It has to do that at some point, it just wasn't clear to me when and how the buffering happens in the background, so in my hazy view of this I wasn't thinking about that. Excellent!

Comment: So I accepted the answer, but while it's clear to me how this helps with my question, it's not explicitly stated in your reply, maybe you'd like to add that: I can signal, from my UDP thread, to the main program, that bind was done - so the main thread can then start the data source, and things will be buffered, whether recv() came first or not.

Comment: @sktpin Thanks!.. I'll add some text to make it clear that the ordering of certain events will be helpful in your case

Comment: @LWimsey: The only asymmetry, if any, is in the application protocol.  For example, DNS is symmetric.  Each DNS server binds to its own port 53, each is authoritative for a subset of domains, and when it needs information on a domain it's not authoritative for, the relayed request and response can be seen to have source and destination of port 53.  (And you can see requests and responses moving in both directions between a pair of ip:53 endpoints -- Both ends are answering requests with data they have, and sending requests for data they don't).  Both ends use the same socket calls.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Linux, it might be possible to use FTRACE to determine whereabouts your receiving thread has got. The function tracing in this allows one (normally in post mortem debugging / analysis) to see the function calls made by a process. I'm pretty sure that this is exposed through some /sys or /proc file system, so it ought to be possible to monitor it live instead.

So if you had your temporary thread looking at the system calls of the receiving thread, it would be able to spot it entering the call to recv().

If FTRACE is not already built into your kernel, you'll need to recompile your kernel to include it. Could be handy - FTRACE + kernelshark is a nice way of debugging your application anyway.